# Cannot install in mongodb in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, ubuntu-13.04

I follow the [instruction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-ubuntu-version-pinning) provided by mongodb.

But seems package mongodb-10gen isn't existed.

```
vagrant@m1:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-10gen
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb-10gen is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'mongodb-10gen' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install the official provided mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed all or part of the ["Configure Package Management"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#configure-package-management-system-apt) step in their instructions. You need to follow those steps to add the official Mongo apt repository to your system, and then update your local package list. After doing this you should be able to install.